# Get Response Class Type in Retrofit2 Interceptor (Caching for Realm)

Tags: android, caching, realm, retrofit2

Not sure if this is even possibly, but I am trying to realize custom caching strategy as cache using Realm. Unfortunately, to copy entities to Realm response bodies need to extend RealmObject. Obviously all of my response bodies does that, but Response and ResponseBody does not know the response class type at the interception moment.

I want to do something like this (but with caching strategy implemented later):

```
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            // Somewhere here will be the caching strategy
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body());
            return response;
        }
    });
```

First - is it even possible? If yes, then how. I don't see any obvious solutions. If this won't be possible I will need to do caching at API consumer client level...

Comment: you are opening local Realm instance that you will never be able to close which can cause problems if done on background non-looper thread, which this probably is considering this is the interceptor of a network request;

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You are right, I should close it when work is finished, but this wasn't the focus of the question. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @Necroqubus: Did the suggestion work?  If so, can you accept it?  ...or, if not, can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can *try* the following:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        // Somewhere here will be the caching strategy
        Object object = response.body();
        if(object != null) {
            try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate((RealmObject)object);
                });
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
});
```

Although I have no guarantees that it would work.